# Dynamic Subdomain Handling in a Web App (Flask)

Tags: python, web, subdomain, flask, wildcard-subdomain

I'm going to be using flask to create a web application, and part of the application will involve a subdomain (for example, user1.appname.org).

I'm not sure how to go about creating these subdomains dynamically in the flask configuration, or how to deploy them to a production server.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

All Flask's routing constructs support the [`subdomain`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=subdomain#url-route-registrations) keyword argument (this includes support for route variables).

```
@app.route("/", subdomain="static")
def static_index():
    """Flask supports static subdomains
    This is available at static.your-domain.tld"""
    return "static.your-domain.tld"

@app.route("/dynamic", subdomain="<username>")
def username_index(username):
    """Dynamic subdomains are also supported
    Try going to user1.your-domain.tld/dynamic"""
    return username + ".your-domain.tld"
```

Comment: Will this work running on the Flask testing localhost server?

Comment: I'm also wondering if there's a way to test this locally. I've tried adding serveral entries to my hosts file., this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @sean How woud you do something similar for custom domains.  A user signs up with subdomain.example.com and then adds a custom domain such as www.mygreatsite.com ?  How would I handle access to this custom domain in a Flask route?

Comment: @Raj - that would depend on how you are setting up those custom domains. (Better to ask a separate question with more details about your setup.)

Comment: You should also be able to test this locally with a free service like xip.io by 37Signals

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain so I can improve the answer?

Comment: @SeanVieira, do you have a boiler-plate for this setup somewhere. i need one.

Comment: How does this work with class based views?

Answer (score 54):

To complement Sean Viera's post, you also need to set the SERVER_NAME config variable.

Documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#SERVER_NAME

> The name and port number of the server. Required for subdomain support
>   (e.g.: 'myapp.dev:5000') Note that localhost does not support
>   subdomains so setting this to “localhost” does not help. Setting a
>   SERVER_NAME also by default enables URL generation without a request
>   context but with an application context.

To test locally you need to add entries to your `hosts` file, like this:

```
127.0.0.1       cvshark.local
127.0.0.1       robert.cvshark.local
127.0.0.1       www.cvshark.local
```

Comment: I don't understand the example they give: 'myapp.dev:5000'. Is myapp the subdomain and dev the hostname?

Comment: @compie Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This is the better answer; it goes beyond the documentation and solves the trickier stuff.

Comment: but can you add DYNAMIC entries to the host file?

Comment: @MichaelIlie Yes you can, look at the last route in Sean Vieira answer.