# how can my flask app create a subdomain automatically for my user?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, saas, flask-login

I have built a flask application that will be used by restaurants, I want to know how I can make the app give each restaurant a subdomain and own database when they register for an account on our landing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question sounds like it is more about the Domain Name System than Flask.

You're saying that your server will start running, and then days or weeks later a new client will register with some new `restaurant_name`, e.g. "spicytacos". You would like to create a new spicytacos.example.com FQDN in the Domain Name System, with A or AAAA record pointing at your webserver. Then your flask app will be able to recognize the restaurant's name in `request.args` and respond appropriately.

If you're running the primary nameserver of example.com with BIND9 or similar, then it's just a matter of re-writing the zone config file and sending a HUP signal.

If you prefer to let some other firm handle nameservice details, then probably a `*` wildcard record is your best bet. It should be a CNAME or address record pointing to your server.

A middle path would be to use a DDNS (dynamic DNS) service, perhaps from afraid.org or No-IP. That is another way of binding a FQDN to an address, which gives you a little more control.

Please refer to [How to create dynamic subdomains in a Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803176/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomains-in-a-flask-application#answer-16840125) to see how `@app.before_request` can parse out novel hostnames during request routing.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i'd like my app to do it for me (not me going on AWS to create a subdomain and clone the whole app there) but let me try what you suggested and will let you know if it works!