# Flask Subdomain with Heroku and Godaddy (SERVER_NAME issues)

Tags: python, heroku, flask, subdomain

I am trying to set up a subdomain on a flask server, which has a server hosted on Heroku and a custom domain hosted on GoDaddy. I have verified that my subdomain is working locally. The subdomain is a separate blueprint in my app. My setup in flask is:

```
blueprint = Blueprint('blueprint', __name__, template_folder="templates", subdomain="blueprint")

@blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello Mate"
```

and then

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = os.environ['MY_SERVER_NAME']
from blueprint.views import blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

On my local machine, I set up a custom record in my hosts file (`/etc/hosts`) to test the subdomain. The file has the entries:

```
127.0.0.1 virtual.local
127.0.0.1 blueprint.virtual.local
```

If I navigate to `blueprint.virtual.local:5000`, I see the intended result (a page that just says `Hello Mate`. I believe this proves my subdomain settings are set up properly, at least within flask.

I push my code to my heroku app, and this is where I start running into problems. My heroku site has a custom domain associated with it from before. I start by adding an entry for the new subdomain. Running `heroku domains` in the terminal gives me:

```
=== myapp Domain Names
blueprint.mysite.com
www.mysite.com
myapp.herokuapp.com
mysite.com
```

The first issue I am running into is that I can only either view my site on the heroku URL or the custom domain. This is a result of `app.config['SERVER_NAME']` (which I set to get my subdomain working) being linked to either the heroku URL or my custom URL. When it is set to the heroku URL, I can only see the site when I visit it at that URL, and when I go to my custom domain, I get a 404 error. This is reversed when I switch the value of the `SERVER_NAME`.

The second issue is that I cannot get my subdomain to work with GoDaddy on Heroku. In GoDaddy, I create a CNAME record that points my subdomain (`blueprint`) to my heroku site (`myapp.herokuapp.com`). Is this correct? I get a 404 error whenever I visit the subdomain on my custom domain (`blueprint.mysite.com`). I believe this is related to the first issue, but I am not sure. Am I missing any steps?

Any advice on the proper way to set this up, so that I can use Flask subdomains on Heroku, being hosted on a custom domain on GoDaddy? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're confusing Flask Blueprints and Heroku apps. A flask *app* (and its containing git repository, in this case) is one and only one Heroku *app* (a single domain, or subdomian... but crucially, only one of them).

A Flask Blueprint is a way of organizing individual sections of a single Flask app to be more modular.

To create Heroku Apps at `awesome.darrellsilver.com` and `sauce.darrellsilver.com` you should set up two independent Flask Apps, in two independent Git repos.

Comment: Interesting - what is the use case of built in Flask subdomains, then (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021691/dynamic-subdomain-handling-in-a-web-app-flask)? Is it that they are useful, but not when hosting on Heroku?

Comment: Tried this out, and deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I had 404 issues when I switched to an SSL endpoint using Flask on Heroku. All I had to do was change the app.config "SERVER_NAME" to the new "www.CUSTOMENDPOINTNAME.com" address from the "CUSTOMENDPOINTNAME.herokuapp.com" which was there previously.