# Does Flask support regular expressions in its subdomain?

Tags: python, regex, flask, subdomain

In flask I know it can use subdomain, but I want to set some different subdomain in same routing.
Is there a way we can use regular expressions in subdomain just like in its URL routing?like:

```
@app.route('/', subdomain='<regex("www|test"):subdomain>')
def example(subdomain):
    return "{}".format(subdomain)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But there is new question, if I don't want the argument like this one, what should I do?

```
@app.route('/', subdomain='<regex("www|test"):subdomain>')
def example():
    return "test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "like in its URL routing"? `@app.route()` doesn't support regex by default.

Comment: I mean that I can simply implement it in the routing，But I can't in subdomain.

Comment: Maybe I can achieve It by same way?I just try it

Comment: Maybe show an example of what you need and how it's different from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021691/dynamic-subdomain-handling-in-a-web-app-flask

Comment: This is not what I want, but anyway I implement it

Answer (score 0):

I found the werkzeug use the same way to parse domain_url and URL path in [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L734)!

so I can implement it by this:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

app = Flask(__name__)


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    SERVER_NAME = 'local.dev:9090'


class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
        super(RegexConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
        self.regex = items[0]


app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

@app.route('/', subdomain='<regex("www|test"):subdomain>')
def example(subdomain):
    return "{}".format(subdomain)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and if you want to test in local, you maybe edit your host like:

```
127.0.0.1       www.local.dev
127.0.0.1       local.dev
127.0.0.1       test.local.dev
```